# PF DataTable Filter Function Not Working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

Prime faces : 6.0 I tried to enable global search functionality in a PrimeFaces DataTable, similar to what I saw in the PrimeFaces showcase.
Any search string that I enter returns an empty result set. I am able to implement pagination, but global search is an issue.
Here is my code:

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="pres" value="#{presBean.presentations}" rows ="10"
    paginator="true" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
    rowsPerPageTemplate="10,25,100" widgetVar="presTable" **filteredValue="#{presBean.filteredPres}"**>

    <p:column headerText="Title" sortBy="#{pres.title}">
    <!--f:facet name="header" sortBy="#{pres.title}">
        <h:outputText value="Title" />
    </f:facet-->
    <h:outputText value="#{pres.title}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Presenter" sortBy="#{pres.presenter}">
    <!--f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Presenter" />
    </f:facet-->
    <h:outputText value="#{pres.presenter}" />
</p:column>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

your `value` and `filteredValue` should not point to the same bean-property. `filteredValue` should target another (initial empty) list with the same signature.

PF will move results matching the filter into this list, and also clears this list upon every call to `.filter()` - so you are just throwing away your "non-filtered" result at the moment, because you are pointing to the same list.

Comment: I updated my original post to include your suggestions. The bean object I'm reading from has 9 fields. Still it did not work. Do I need to add any code for  filterdValue?. Right now what I have in my bean for filteredValue is an ArrayList of presentation objects.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I did not do  the filter on all fields. Once I added the filters to all fields of the table it started working.